# How can you run an ldap search using variables and a not filter?

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

```
ldapsearch -h 1.0.24.24 -p 389 -x -t -LLL -S cn -D 
cn=user,ou=resources,o=otherresource,c=xx -w server101 -b ou=Non-
Staff,ou=people,o=test,c=us '(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
(createTimestamp<=$month_8)(!(nEApps=*))(nEDHHSNFAccNbr=\00)
(nECreatedBy=cioSelfRegistered)(loginTime<=$month_3))' dn
```

I can only use my variables if the filters are surrounded by double quotes
and I can only use the not filter if they are surround by single quotes is there a way to make this work in the same query?

Comment: Where are your variables?

Comment: month_8=$(date –d “-8 month” ‘+%Y%m%d000000Z’)

 month_3=$(date –d “-3 month” ‘+%Y%m%d000000Z’

ex. 20170904000000Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is a special character (it does a command history substitution) in interactive mode, but not in a script. Is this supposed to be something you'll type in interactively, or something embedded in a script? If the latter, you can just use double-quotes, and the `!` won't be a problem.

If you're using this interactively, there are a coupe of options. One is to mix quoting modes in a single argument , as in `"double-quoted-section"'single-quoted-section'"another-quoted-section"`. This looks weird, but works fine. Something like this:

```
ldapsearch -h 1.0.24.24 -p 389 -x -t -LLL -S cn \
-D cn=user,ou=resources,o=otherresource,c=xx -w server101 \
-b ou=Non-Staff,ou=people,o=test,c=us \
"(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(createTimestamp<=$month_8)("'!'"(nEApps=*))(nEDHHSNFAccNbr=\00)(nECreatedBy=cioSelfRegistered)(loginTime<=$month_3))" dn
                                                          ^^^^^
```

Alternately, you could define a variable as `!` (using single-quotes), then use that variable inside double-quotes:

```
exclamation='!'
ldapsearch -h 1.0.24.24 -p 389 -x -t -LLL -S cn \
-D cn=user,ou=resources,o=otherresource,c=xx -w server101 \
-b ou=Non-Staff,ou=people,o=test,c=us \
"(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(createTimestamp<=$month_8)($exclamation(nEApps=*))(nEDHHSNFAccNbr=\00)(nECreatedBy=cioSelfRegistered)(loginTime<=$month_3))" dn
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The `!` filter only 'needs' single quotes because of the `*`, which the shell will attempt to expand itself as a wildcard.

Solution: escape it.